# What does "cumulative" mean in the following paragraph?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I was reading the following paragraph and saw the **latest cumulative update**:

> Continue to work through the installation process, selecting the
> default values. Once the installation is complete, install the  latest
> **cumulative** update for SQL Server. At the time of writing, the latest
> update is available at https://support.microsoft.com/
> en-us/help/4527377/cumulative-update-18-for-sql-server-2017, although
> newer updates may have been released by the time  you read this
> chapter.

I've searched for a difination for **cumulative** in some dictioanaries, for example in **Collins Dictionary** founded the following definition with some examples:

> **Definition**: If a series of events have a cumulative effect, each event
> makes the effect greater.

> Simple pleasures, such as a walk on a sunny
> day, have a cumulative effect on our mood.  The benefits from eating
> fish are cumulative.  Synonyms: collective, increasing, aggregate,
> amassed   More Synonyms of cumulative cumulatively ADVERB His
> administration was plagued by one petty scandal after another,
> cumulatively very damaging

and I've founded a definition in Longman Dictionary too:

> increasing gradually as more of something is added or happens

First of all, I couldn't recognize which of these definition to use to know what **cumulative** means in the following example:

> The benefits from eating fish are **cumulative**

and then, what does it mean by **cumulative** in the following paragraph (which is about SQL Server installation in windows OS) :

> Continue to work through the installation process, selecting the
> default values. Once the installation is complete, install the  latest
> **cumulative** update for SQL Server. At the time of writing, the latest
> update is available at https://support.microsoft.com/
> en-us/help/4527377/cumulative-update-18-for-sql-server-2017, although
> newer updates may have been released by the time  you read this
> chapter.

I would be grateful if anyone give me some synonyms or alternatives for **cumulative** here too.

Comment: Both definitions apply to the sentence about fish. The more times you eat fish, or the more of it you eat, the more health benefits you get.

Comment: PS I would recommend that you use a spell-checker. There are lots of typing errors in your question.

Comment: [Please be more careful with spelling. Your questions had a lot of spelling mistakes.]

Comment: This term has a very specific meaning in the software industry, but you can answer this question by typing "What is a cumulative update?" into Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of 'cumulative' that applies here is:

> Increasing or enlarging by successive addition.

Software updates are often sent out *incrementally*. A 'cumulative' update is one that collects several incremental updates together into one larger package and updates your system as one.

Answer (score 0):

An addition to the previous that increases the amount or in this case improves the existing program with more updates or multiple updates and they are cumulative because they continue to be put out to that same program.
Another example is how radiation exposure becomes cumulative in the body the more it is subjected to the UV rays. It's a continuum and adds up with each exposure you get.Think of the cumulative effects of tanning and each time the UV rays are absorbed by the skin they accumulate with time. This is cumulative. Radiation has cumulative effects.